# Checking Lowercases and Uppercases on a string

Tags: kotlin

So basically I need to run a program that checks if the first character is an uppercase. If it is it goes through. Then I need to check if the rest of my characters are lowercases. I currently have this code, but the problem is, if I insert uppercases on the string and then end with a lowercase, it follows through but it was not supposed to. The program needs to ask the user for another "name" if it has uppercases after the first character. (sorry if it was not explicit my english is not that great :/ )

```
var lowercases = ' '
do {
    println("Insert a name")
    val name = readLine()!!.toString()
    val First = name[0]
    if (First.isUpperCase()) {
        for (caracter in 1 until name.length) {
            lowercases = name[caracter]
            if (lowercases.isLowerCase()) {


            }
        }
    } else{
        println("olha nao da")
    }
} while (First.isLowerCase() || lowercases.isUpperCase())
```

Comment: Clarify this - would "Working group" be an acceptable string where as either "Working Group" or "working group" be invalid?

Comment: Using regular expressions would be the best option...

Answer (score 4):

I'd split out the check to a separate function.  That not only keeps the logic simpler, but also allows you to give it a descriptive name.  And it fits well as an extension function on String:

```kotlin
fun String.isTitleCase()
    = isNotEmpty() && this[0].isUpperCase() && drop(1).all{ it.isLowerCase() }
```

This means: a `String` is title-case if it's not empty, its first character is upper-case, and all characters except the first are lower-case.  (If you wanted to handle ligatures too, you'd also check `isTitleCase()` on the first character, as well as `isUpperCase()`.)

(Of course, you could write that as a block-style, multi-line function, possibly with a loop and `return`s — but when all else is equal, I prefer the shorter version!)

Your main code then doesn't need to worry how the check is done, and becomes simpler:

```kotlin
while (true) {
    println("Enter a name:")
    val name = readLine()
    if (name != null && name.isTitleCase()) {
        // Do stuff
        break
    } else {
        println("olha nao da")
    }
}
```

(I've replaced the `!!` with a null check, which is much safer.  I've also changed the `do`…`while` loop to a `while` loop with a `break`, to avoid repeating the check.  And there's no need to call `toString()`, as `readLine()` already gives you a `String` or a `null`.)

---

*Edited to add:*

In practice, once [`readLine()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html) returns `null`, it will continue to do so — which would leave the code above in an endless loop. (This can happen if the input is redirected from a file and you've reached the end, or you type the end-of-file character e.g. Ctrl+D, or you're running on an online IDE that doesn't support stdin.)

So ideally you'd have an explicit check for that condition, e.g.:

```kotlin
    // …
    if (name == null)
        break
    else if (name.isTitleCase()) {
        // …
```

Answer (score -1):

using regular expression is faster and cleaner:

```
val regex = """[A-Z][^A-Z]+""".toRegex()
var name
do{
    println("Insert a name")
    name = readLine()?.toString() :? "."
}while(!regex matches name)
```

---

another way:

```
do {
    println("Insert a name")
    val name = readLine()!!.toString()
    var curChar = name[0]
    if(name.length > 1){
        if (curChar.isUpperCase()) {
           for (i in 1 until name.length) {
               curChar = name[i]
               if (curChar.isLowerCase()) {
                  // you send no code for this block
               }else{
                  break//as you wish if character is uppercase asks from user again
               }
           }
        } else{
           println("olha nao da")//your message as you send
        }
    }
} while (curChar.isUpperCase())
```